# Chart.js: call method outside of onRefresh() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have attached the code snippet. I have a method in `rand()` in HomeComponent class and i want to call it for y axis, but from current scenario it is not possible because whenever `onRefresh()` get called `this.rand()` is not reachable, which is expected. Because `onRefresh()` get called from core.js which is core library. So please help to get this done

```html
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
....
..
options: any = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: 'realtime',

          realtime: {
            onRefresh(chart: any) {


              chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset: any) {
                dataset.data.push({
                  x: Date.now(),

                  **y: this.rand()**
                });
              });
              chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = chart.helpers.niceNum(20);
              chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = chart.helpers.niceNum(180);
            },

            delay: 2000
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
          value: '120',
          borderColor: 'tomato',
          borderWidth: 2
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
          value: '70',
          borderColor: 'blue',
          borderWidth: 2
        }
      ]
      //drawTime: "afterDraw" // (default)
    }
  };
  ....
  ....
  
  rand(): Number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
  }
  }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your implementation of `rand`, would it not be sufficient to simply do what you're doing for the X axis data?

i.e

```
                dataset.data.push({
                  x: Date.now(),
                  y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
                });
```

Comment: yeah it is possible... but my actual function is different one. This function rand() is added only for example purpose.

Answer (score 0):

problem can be solved by declaring global variable out the class HomeComponent and in the body of the constructor of HomeComponent, assigned 'this' to declared variable. After that we can access methods and instance variables easily.

Thanks :)